# Aligning types of generically created model and service that consumes model

Tags: java, generics

Okay, this is a complex problem, so I'm gonna try my best to distill it to a simple format.

The overarching goal of what I'm trying to do is to create an interface and a few implementations of said interface. The interface has a single method with a void return and a single argument.

The single argument is a POJO that has subclasses. Each implementation of the interface consumes a version of the POJO: some fields of the POJO are shared by all implementations, other fields are specific to the implementation.

The current architecture of this that I have going looks like this:

The POJOs

```
public abstract class ExecutionContext {
    String name;
}
```

```
public class FirstExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext {
    int id;
}
```

```
public class SecondExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext {
    String description;
}
```

The interface and implementations

```
public interface Executor<T extends ExecutionContext> {
    void execute(T context);
}
```

```
public interface FirstExecutor implements Executor<FirstExecutionContext> {
    void execute(FirstExecutionContext context) { ... }
}
```

```
public interface SecondExecutor implements Executor<SecondExecutionContext> {
    void execute(SecondExecutionContext context) { ... }
}
```

So, question one: does this structure make sense?

The next problem comes when I try to actually call this method. The problem here is that I need to generically create both the Executor and the Context, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to architect this to chain the calls without errors of some sort.

I started with a calling class that looks something like this (just ignore the if conditional logic, seemed simpler than setting up an enum)

```
public class ExecutorWorker {
    public void buildAndCallExecutor(String name, int id, String description, String type) {
        if (type.equals("FIRST")) {
            FirstExecutor executor = new FirstExecutor();
            FirstExecutionContext executionContext = new FirstExecutionContext();
            executionContext.setName(name);
            executionContext.setId(id);

            executor.execute(executionContext);
        } else if (type.equals("SECOND")) {
            SecondExecutor executor = new SecondExecutor();
            SecondExecutionContext executionContext = new SecondExecutionContext();
            executionContext.setName(name);
            executionContext.setDescription(description);

            executor.execute(executionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works, but completely ignores the abstraction of the interfaces and ends up with a fair amount of duplicated code (especially as the construction of `ExecutionContext` becomes more complex). However, this is where I've hit a wall: how can I refactor this code to be more generic?

In particular, the issue I consistently run into is generically constructing both the `ExecutionContext` and the `Executor`, then having them get along. Here's an attempt with wildcards (just focusing on refactoring the Executor for now):

```
public class ExecutorWorker {
    public void buildAndCallExecutor(String name, int id, String description, String type) {
        Executor<? extends ExecutionContext> executor;
        ExecutionContext executionContext;

        if (type.equals("FIRST")) {
            executor = new FirstExecutor();
            FirstExecutionContext firstExecutionContext = new FirstExecutionContext();
            firstExecutionContext.setName(name);
            firstExecutionContext.setId(id);
        } else if (type.equals("SECOND")) {
            executor = new SecondExecutor();
            SecondExecutionContext secondExecutionContext = new SecondExecutionContext();
            secondExecutionContext.setName(name);
            secondExecutionContext.setDescription(description);
        }

        executor.execute(executionContext); // compile error: required: capture of ? extends ExecutionContext, provided: ExecutionContext
    }
}
```

I also tried this with generics, but also to no avail:

```
public class ExecutorWorker {
    public <T extends ExecutionContext> void buildAndCallExecutor(String name, int id, String description, String type) {
        Executor<T> executor;
        T executionContext;

        if (type.equals("FIRST")) {
            executor = new FirstExecutor(); // compile error: required type: Executor<T>, provided: FirstExecutor
            FirstExecutionContext firstExecutionContext = new FirstExecutionContext();
            firstExecutionContext.setName(name);
            firstExecutionContext.setId(id);
        } else if (type.equals("SECOND")) {
            executor = new SecondExecutor(); // compile error: required type: Executor<T>, provided: SecondExecutor
            SecondExecutionContext secondExecutionContext = new SecondExecutionContext();
            secondExecutionContext.setName(name);
            secondExecutionContext.setDescription(description);
        }

        executor.execute(executionContext); 
    }
}
```

The fundamental issue with each approach is that I can't figure out how to align the generics between the Executor and the Context - for some subtype of `ExecutionContext`, I want to construct an instance of that subtype and instantiate a subtype of `Executor` that consumes that subtype. How can I align these two actions? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reImplementation of Executor that allows to call all setters from executor, for example using an interface that implements those setters

```
public interface setter<T extends ExecutionContext> {
    void execute(T context);
    public T setDescritpion(String description);
    public T setId(int id);
}

public abstract class ExecutionContext implements setter{
    String name;
}
```

Now you will be foced to implement the missing methods in the non-abstract childs, if a child doesent have a particular field just do nothing in the specific setter.

Then I think a factory would be nice so you can get the context you need at runtime

```
public class ExecutionContextFactory {
    public static ExecutionContext getExecutionContext(TypeEnum type) {
        switch (type){
            case FIRST: return new FirstExecutionContext ();
            case SECOND: return new SecondExecutionContext ();
        }
    }
}
```

and a nearly identical one for the executors.

Now you can simply do

```
public void buildAndCallExecutor(String name, int id, String description, String type) {
        ExecutorFactory
            .getExecutor(type).execute(
                 ExecutionContextFactory
                    .getExecutionContext(type)
                    .setName(name)
                    .setDescription(description)
                    .setId(id)
            )
}
```

I think it should work, not tested though.

Another thing you could do is reflection, you could implement in the superclasses  some utility methods that allows to acces fields and methods and set those fields using simply the name of the Fields you want. There are many possibilities, it really depends on the application context

Comment: Interesting! I played around a bit with the idea of somehow combining the executor and the POJO into one class but never came up with a pattern I was happy with. I didn't think about making an interface implemented by the abstract class though, maybe something like that could work. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: So, part of the issue I'm having with this solution has to do with my oversimplification of the problem. Ideally, I'd like to use the builder pattern instead of setters. In addition, I'm using spring dependency injection, and the `Executor` has a number of fields I'd normally use dependency injection for. Combining the POJO and the Executor into one class makes this pretty tricky. I'll keep toying around with it though, it seems like it would work if I'm willing to make some concessions in other areas.

Comment: if you don't mind losing some performances you could do the last thing i suggested, being having some methods in the superclass which reflectively set the fieds you need at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> „…*`buildAndCallExecutor(…)`*…“

Anytime you have a method with *`And`* in its name, that's a cue to refactor that method into two more cohesive methods.

My advice is to spin off the two different aspects of *`buildAndCallExecutor(…)`* into two separate methods: (***1***) *`build()`*  and (***2***) *`execute()`*.

> „*…There should be a way to declare the interface-typed variable…*“

[*Here's a working demo of a more cohesive way to do that*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_313602)…

```
…
build( String name, U unambiguous, Type whichType ) {

    /* declare the interface-typed variable */
    Executioner< U > executioner;
    
    switch( whichType ) { 
        case FIRST: 
            /* assign the variable */
            executioner = new Executioner< >( new FirstExecutor< U >( ), new FirstExecutionContext< U >( name, unambiguous ) );
            break;
        case SECOND:
            executioner = new Executioner< >( new SecondExecutor< U >( ), new SecondExecutionContext< U >( name, unambiguous ) );
            break;
         …
    }
}
…
```

> „*…call the method outside the if block…*“

[*I demonstrate*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_313602) a simple, more cohesive implementation of that as…

```
public class ExecutorWorker {

    public < U > void execute( Set< Executioner< U > > executioners ) {
        
        executioners.stream( ).forEach( Executioner::execute );
    }
}
```

Then you *`build()`* and *`call()`* separately…

```
…
Builder builder = new Builder( );

ExecutorWorker worker = new ExecutorWorker( );
    
Set< Executioner< Integer > > work = builder.build( 666 );

worker.execute( work );
…
```

An *experimental* run of that prints out…

```
SecondExecutor< S > { } - executing SecondExecutionContext< D > { name: SECOND, description: 666 }
FirstExecutor< F > { } - executing FirstExecutionContext< U > { name: FIRST, id: 666 }

            EXPERIMENT SUCCESSFUL
```

---

> „*…Okay, this is a complex problem…*“

For fun, [*I did this additional experiment*](http://jdoodle.com/ia/UL) to test out the degree of complexity the above design can be extended to.

I demonstrate a working implementation of giving a *complex* *`ExecutionContext`* to a *complex* *`Executor`* that *`executes()`* other *simpler* *`Executors`*…

```
…    
Set< Executioner< String > > woyk = builder.build( "K.I.S.S." );
        
Executor< ExecutionContext< Set< Executioner< String > > >, Set< Executioner< String > > > executor = new ComplexWorker< > ( );
        
ExecutionContext< Set< Executioner< String > > > complexWoyk = new ComplexExecutionCtx< >("It's complicated", woyk );
        
executor.execute( complexWoyk );
…
```

That prints…

```
…
ComplexWorker< CW >{ } - executing ComplexExecutionCtx< E, CTX > { name: It's complicated, complex: [executable.Executioner@27f674d, executable.Executioner@1d251891] }
FirstExecutor< F >{ } - executing FirstExecutionCtx< U > { name: FIRST, id: K.I.S.S. }
SecondExecutor< S >{ } - executing SecondExecutionCtx< D > { name: SECOND, description: K.I.S.S. }
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it [*like this*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_313602) if it were me…

```
public class ExecutorWorker {
    
    public void buildAndCallExecutor( String name, int id, String description, String type ) {

        if ( type.equals( "FIRST" ) ) {
            Executor< FirstExecutionContext > executor = new FirstExecutor( );
            FirstExecutionContext firstExecutionContext = new FirstExecutionContext( );
            firstExecutionContext.setName( name );
            firstExecutionContext.setId( id );
            
            executor.execute( firstExecutionContext );
            
        } else if ( type.equals( "SECOND" ) ) {
            Executor< SecondExecutionContext > executor = new SecondExecutor( );
            SecondExecutionContext secondExecutionContext = new SecondExecutionContext( );
            secondExecutionContext.setName( name );
            secondExecutionContext.setDescription( description );

            executor.execute( secondExecutionContext );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're comfortable with the first way? I gotta say, I'm just really not within my use case. In my actual case there's 3 different implementations of `ExecutorService` and the context has 9 shared fields, plus a bunch of other sharing of contextual models. Doing separate logic for each individual path is going to result in a TON of code duplication.

Comment: „*So you're comfortable with the first way?*“ — What are you referring to as „*the first way*“? In your *first* way the static type that _`buildAndCallExecutor()`_ calls the _`execute()`_  method on, is a concrete implementation: _`FirstExecutor executor = new FirstExecutor()`_. In your *second* way, the static type _`buildAndCallExecutor()`_ calls _`execute()`_ on, is the super type instantiated with a wildcard: _`Executor<? extends ExecutionContext> executor...`_ Then your *third* way the static type is the super type, but instantiated with a type variable:  _`Executor<T> executor...`_

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice the difference there. Good point, that is a better version, using the interface instead of the the implementation. Still though, it doesn't really fix the root of the problem, which is the duplication of code.

Comment: „*...the duplication of code...*“ — What, *specifically* in your code snippets are you referring to as „*the duplication of code*“? Are you referring to the _`if`_ block specifically?

Comment: „*it doesn't really fix the root of the problem*“ — My solution focuses on ([*and resolves*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_313602)) these other, more immediate, *roots* of your problem: (***1***) _`compile error: required: capture of ? extends ExecutionContext, provided: ExecutionContext`_ (***2***) _`compile error: required type: Executor<T>, provided: SecondExecutor`_ and (_**3**_) „_I can't figure out how to align the generics between the Executor and the Context_“.

Comment: There's still 2 duplications. First, we set `name` for both, even though it's a shared field in the parent class `ExecutionContext`. If there were more fields in `ExecutionContext` each if block would just get bigger and bigger with more and more duplication. Second, we call `executor.execute(...)` in both if blocks, despite it being a shared method of an interface. There should be a way to declare the interface-typed variable, assign the variable within the if block, then call the method outside the if block. This is the duplication I was primarily focusing on in my 2nd and 3rd solution.